# How to store variable data in Laravel log in to file using "info" function?

Tags: php, laravel, api, logging, cron

I want to print a variable value in Laravel log file. How can I do that ?
like I have this -

`\Log::info("Group Message Cron");`

Comment: `\Log::info(json_encode($variable, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i solved this with this -
```\Log::info("Message $msg is being sent to $mobile");```

Comment: It all depends on if it's part of the string, or you're trying to log a more complex variable. Your code works for a simple string, Sachin's works for an array or object. You can also use `Log::info(print_r($variable, true));` for the complex structure.

Comment: Actually you should be importing Laravel's Log Facade. Using the  \ is not the best practice

Comment: @Rotimi But ultimately that part is irrelevant to the question being asked here  The question is asking how to log a variable inside of an `::info()` call, not how to use/import the `Log` class. Also, for 1-off testing, it's easier/quicker to just do `\Log::info('This is a test');` instead of also including `use Log;`, then `Log::info()`; that's 2 spots you need to delete when you're done with this testing code instead of 1.

Comment: @TimLewis it is not a must, but still a valid point. I've had issues with classes of the same name clashing due to the use of the backslahes. Hence why I said "best practice".